# What is the Cookie Domain in a Cross-domain PHP Call by JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, php, iframe, cookies, cross-domain

If I have JavaScript in a page in domain here.com that calls PHP that resides under domain there.com, does that PHP access cookies in here.com or there.com? Would wrapping an IFRAME make a difference?

Answer (score 1):

The cookie domain is the target of the HTTP request: there.com. Wrapping in an `iframe` makes no difference.

Comment: That's what I thought, but when I call from here.com my remote PHP to grab a cookie named auth in the domain there.com, the value reported is "" instead of "499d73a09e0", the value stored in auth. When the same PHP is called at there.com the value is correctly returned as "499d73a09e0". What am I missing?

Comment: Are you trying to access the cookie from javascript? If so, keep in mind that any cookie marked as `HttpOnly` will be unreadable by javascript.

Comment: A second cookie I created, named hash2 with HttpOnly false, is still read blank like the first cookie, named hash: setcookie("hash",$hash,time()+3600*24*365,"/") setcookie("hash2",$hash,time()+3600*24*365,"/",null,false,false). What else am I missing?